# Excel formula to find sum of difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel sheet with 2 columns: baseline, current.
the baseline if base prices and the current is real price.
for example:

```
base | curr
-----|-----
10   | 15
8    | 8
9    | 5
1    | 2
-----|-----
27   | 28
```

Now, I need the difference if HIGHER current prices.. in our example, the first and last line have bigger current price, so i need the formula to return 6 (=15-10+2-1).

is there any way to do it in excel formula? I need to loop on all the rows and mark the curr>base rows, and then do the sum(curr-base) for everyone of the results.

I tried it with sumproduct, and other functions (sumifs and such) with no help...

any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it not be acceptable to just add a calculated column for this?

Comment: The sum(base)-sum(curr) will return 1 (28-27), I need it to return 6, for the sum of the bigger curr culomn..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer.. no need for new column or so..

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B3>A1:A3),--(B1:B3-A1:A3))
```

column base = A, curr = B

Thanks for trying..

Comment: Nice find. Could you tell me what the `--()` does?

Comment: --() create new array of the "TRUE" values = 1 , FALSE = 0. in our example it will create : {1,0,0,1} , the second --() will return the diffs between the new columns, so multiple the TRUE criteria with the all diffs, will give you the some of the only TRUE (multiple by 0 is 0 :) ).

Comment: @CustomX - the double minus is hard to search for but not too bad if you use the technical term [Excel double unary](http://www.google.com?q=Excel+double+unary).

Answer (score 11):

If you don't like those `--` you can also get the formula this way:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B3>A1:A3)*(B1:B3-A1:A3))
```

*Note:* the `*` replaced the `,`

Answer (score 1):

I would make a new column containing `=IF(B1 > A1;B1-A1;0)` and make total of that.

Comment: Cannot do it.. I have ~100 curr columns, and it added daily.. cannot create 2 columns instead of 1.. sorry

Comment: @gabi if it's formatted as a table, the formulae will automatically get copied as new rows are added.

Comment: new columns, 1 per day (each column is about 100 rows), all of the columns look at the same baseline.

Answer (score 0):

Add another column, compute the greater one of the two there using an IF statement.

Sum that column for your result.